# How can I make this modal persistent?

Tags: javascript, css, modal-dialog, bootstrap-modal

I am looking for a way to make this modal persistent once it show up. As it's presented here, the user can close it with a simple click outside of the div.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
  <h2>Activate Modal with JavaScript</h2>
  <!-- Modal -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
    
      <!-- Modal content-->
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <p>Some text in the modal.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      
    </div>
  </div>
  
</div>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(window).load(function(){
    $('#myModal').modal('show');
  });
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Is there a way to block this modal so it's still there even with a mouse click outside of it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To "persist the modal" (aka prevent hiding) hook into the hide event and return false to prevent hiding.

```
$("#myModal").on('hide.bs.modal', function () {  
  return false
});
```

Here's a full code example.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
  <h2>Persistent Modal</h2>
  <!-- Modal -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
    
      <!-- Modal content-->
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <h4 class="modal-title">My Persistent Modal</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <p>I'm here for good. Can't hide me.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      
    </div>
  </div>
  
</div>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(window).load(function(){
    $('#myModal').modal('show');
  });
  
  $("#myModal").on('hide.bs.modal', function () {  
    return false
  });
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

**Edit**: To hide the modal, redefine the response to the hide event before calling `hide()`. The following function does this. You can execute the function whenever is appropriate (e.g. on a button click).

```
function hideMyModal () {
  $("#myModal").on('hide.bs.modal', function () { });
  $("#myModal").hide()
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this ought to get you started. You can fiddle around with different values like color, timing, etc.

```css
html, body {
    margin: 0;
    background: #878787;
}

h2 {
    text-align: center;
}

.modal-content {
    position: absolute;
    top: 10px;
    animation: modal 300ms linear;
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-radius: 5px;
    text-align: center;
    background: #fff;
    width: 90%;
    left: 10px;
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 1px #5f5f5f; 
    opacity: 0;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    animation-delay: 500ms;
}

@keyframes modal {
    0% { opacity: 0; top: 0px}
    5% { z-index: 2; }
    100% { opacity: 1; z-index: 2; top: 10px}
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <h2>Activate Modal with JavaScript</h2>
    <!-- Modal -->
    <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <!-- Modal content-->
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <p>Some text in the modal.</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Is code-only answer acceptable?

```js
BootstrapDialog.show({
  title: 'Modal Header',
  message: 'Some text in the modal.',
  closeByBackdrop: false // <- This prevents closing the dialog by clicking outside
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap3-dialog/1.34.9/css/bootstrap-dialog.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap3-dialog/1.34.9/js/bootstrap-dialog.js"></script>
```

More examples please see here http://nakupanda.github.io/bootstrap3-dialog/