# JavaScript Alert closing alone

Tags: javascript

I have a JavaScript alert that returns on my page when it is clicked on menu2, however it does not stop in my page. How do I leave the alert in stop mode on the page. My code below is what I have so far.

**HTML**

```html
  <ul id="menu">
    <li id="menu1"><a href="/glpi/front/helpdesk.public.php" title="Home" class="itemP">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li id="menu2"><a href="/glpi/front/helpdesk.public.php?create_ticket=1" title="Cria um chamado" class="itemP">Cria um chamado</a>
    </li>
    <li id="menu3"><a href="/glpi/front/ticket.php" title="Chamados" class="itemP">Chamados</a>
    </li>
    <li id="menu4"><a href="/glpi/front/reservationitem.php" title="Reservas" class="itemP">Reservas</a>
    </li>
    <li id="menu5"><a href="/glpi/front/helpdesk.faq.php" title="FAQ" class="itemP">FAQ</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    < /html>
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
echo "<script type='text/javascript'>
      $(document).ready(function(){
          $('#menu2').click(function(){
            alert('Text');
          })
      });
    </script>";
```

Comment: This may be of use... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35067259/how-can-i-make-this-modal-persistent

Comment: is the menu an `<a>` tag? You would likely want to `preventDefault` in your callback or else you will get the alert and once the user clicks "ok" the page will go to whatever `href` is in the link.

Comment: I want the alert to return and do not pass the href link

Comment: @RenatoLazaro I dont think you're understanding what Jon is saying. Elements have default actions and if don't disable the default actions like using `event.preventDefault()` then the default action will occur. In your case, it's possible that the default action of a link or a form is causing your page to reload unintentionally. Could you post the HTML code for the menu? That would help.

Comment: <li id="menu2"><a href="/glpi/front/helpdesk.public.php?create_ticket=1" title="Criar Ticket" class="itemP">Criar Tciket</a>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// just add event.preventDefault();
echo "<script type='text/javascript'>
$(document).ready(function(){

  $('#menu2').click(function(event){
   event.preventDefault();
alert('Text');
})
});
</script>";
```

Comment: Same problem after change, after clicking the page menu reloads the alert appears and disappears from the page.

Comment: since we don't know the HTML structure, maybe try `.stopPropagation()`?

Comment: Shadab! The alert does not let you move to the menu2 link /glpi/front/helpdesk.public.php?create_ticket=1

Comment: The alert does not let you move to the menu2 link. I do not want the alert to block the menu.

Comment: Your earlier post was, you wanted to stop reloading of the page. What exactly are you trying to accomplish. Are you trying to navigate to next page or ????

Answer (score 1):

it works for me, here is the demo.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="menu2">click me</button>
echo "<script type='text/javascript'>
                  $(document).ready(function(){
                   $('#menu2').click(function(){
            alert('Text');
                      })
                  });
              </script>";
```

Comment: I want to click on the menu the alert message is on the screen and does not add up unless the user close.